# ACO algorithm on python machine learning

Tags: python

I am trying to understand the code below where it shows the default TSP path on a picture. I understand most of the part except for the polyfit_plot() function. I understand the function in it separately but when combine together I just don't get what it contributes to. I have even tried to delete the function and the result is actually the same, and I don't see where the function is implemented in. Can someone explain it to me? [image]

```
import numpy as np
import math
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

united_states_map = mpimg.imread(r"C:\Users\user\Downloads\archive\united_states_map.png")
def show_cities(path, w=12, h=8):
if isinstance(path, dict):      path = list(path.values())
if isinstance(path[0][0], str): path = [ item[1] for item in path ]    
plt.imshow(united_states_map)    
for x0, y0 in path:
    plt.plot(x0, y0, 'y*', markersize=15)  # y* = yellow star for starting point        
plt.axis("off")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches([w, h])


def show_path(path, starting_city=None, w=12, h=8):
if isinstance(path, dict):      path = list(path.values())
if isinstance(path[0][0], str): path = [ item[1] for item in path ]

starting_city = starting_city or path[0]
x, y = list(zip(*path))
#_, (x0, y0) = starting_city
(x0, y0) = starting_city
plt.imshow(united_states_map)
#plt.plot(x0, y0, 'y*', markersize=15)  # y* = yellow star for starting point
plt.plot(x + x[:1], y + y[:1])  # include the starting point at the end of path
plt.axis("off")
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches([w, h])

 def polyfit_plot(x,y,deg, **kwargs):
coefficients = np.polyfit(x,y,deg,**kwargs)
poly  = np.poly1d(coefficients)
new_x = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1])
new_y = poly(new_x)
plt.plot(x, y, "o", new_x, new_y)
plt.xlim([x[0]-1, x[-1] + 1 ])

terms = []
for p, c in enumerate(reversed(coefficients)):
    term = str(round(c,1))
    if p == 1: term += 'x'
    if p >= 2: term += 'x^'+str(p)
    terms.append(term)        
plt.title(" + ".join(reversed(terms)))   



cities = { "Oklahoma City": (392.8, 356.4), "Montgomery": (559.6, 404.8), "Saint Paul": (451.6, 186.0), "Trenton": (698.8, 239.6), "Salt Lake City": (204.0, 243.2), "Columbus": (590.8, 263.2), "Austin": (389.2, 448.4), "Phoenix": (179.6, 371.2), "Hartford": (719.6, 205.2), "Baton Rouge": (489.6, 442.0), "Salem": (80.0, 139.2), "Little Rock": (469.2, 367.2), "Richmond": (673.2, 293.6), "Jackson": (501.6, 409.6), "Des Moines": (447.6, 246.0), "Lansing": (563.6, 216.4), "Denver": (293.6, 274.0), "Boise": (159.6, 182.8), "Raleigh": (662.0, 328.8), "Atlanta": (585.6, 376.8), "Madison": (500.8, 217.6), "Indianapolis": (548.0, 272.8), "Nashville": (546.4, 336.8), "Columbia": (632.4, 364.8), "Providence": (735.2, 201.2), "Boston": (738.4, 190.8), "Tallahassee": (594.8, 434.8), "Sacramento": (68.4, 254.0), "Albany": (702.0, 193.6), "Harrisburg": (670.8, 244.0) }
cities = list(sorted(cities.items()))
print(len(cities))
show_cities(cities)
show_path(cities)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the function polyfit_plot is unused in the code, so it is never run and as you say it does not affect the outcome.